# How to get most popular post with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-analytics, rubygems

Is there a gem that implements "most popular" functionality for ActiveRecord / Ruby on Rails.

I have a model Article, and I would like to retrieve the most popular / most read articles, using my Google Analytics data.

I have written this in PHP from scratch and was wondering if there is a plugin/gem for Rails available.

Thank you,

Anton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this gem to do most of what I need.

https://github.com/vigetlabs/garb

Answer (score 1):

You can search rubygems here

http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=google+analytics

There are a lot of gems that can integrate with google analytics.